# Should JSON mime be enable on an LMS server or Content server for AICC

Tags: json, adobe-captivate

Should JSON be enabled on i) LMS server, ii) Content server, iii) Both?

Client LMS and Content are hosted on separate servers within the same domain.
Data is submitted from Content to the LMS using the AICC standard.

The issue occurs with Adobe Captivate which is publishing JSON files now. 
The Captivate content appear to hang while loading. 
All support identify that JSON mime type must be supported on the web server.

Regards,
Gary

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to render the output (courses) to the users you would need to allow JSON MIME on both LMS and Content servers since after update 9.0.2.390, Captivate publishes images in JSON format (in HTML output). Earlier images assets were published as .png into the 'dr' directory in published folder. Now webserver has to be configured a MIME type to support the JSON files.